# JPQL complex One to Many join query result

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

I have two simple DTOs,

```
class Post{
   @Id
   private int postId;
   private String text;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post") 
   private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
}

class Comment{
  @Id
  private int commentId;
  private int userId;
  private into text;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "postId")
  private Post post;
}
```

- A post can have multiple comments by different users
- A post can also have multiple comments by the same user

Now, using JPQL, I want to find all the posts along with the user comments, where post has comment(s) by the given user.

So, essentially I want a list of 'Post' objects along with the qualifying comments encapsulated in each post.

Sample SQL might look like this:

```
select *
from post p
inner join comment c
  on p.post_id = c.post_id
where c.user_id = {given user id}
```

Comment: You don't need to use complex query for post's comments

Comment: Are you using spring data ?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I am actually looking for Posts with comments of a particular user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Integer, Post> {

    @Query("select p from Post p inner join p.comments c where c.userId =:userId")
    List<Post> findByCommentsUserId(@Param("userId") Integer userId);
}

Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>(findByCommentsUserId("anyUserId"));
```

I write this code without executing it so It is pseodocode but it will be similar

Comment: Would this result in all Posts that have comments by a particular user? And also, that all the Post objects will have only the related comments populated?

Comment: above query is all posts which have comments with specific user.

Comment: If there is no comment or there is no user then you can not find.

Comment: If there are 3 comments C1, C2 and C3 for a Post P1, such that C1 & C2 are made by User U1, whereas C3 is made by user U2. 

In such a case, I believe if I pass on a condition to fetch all posts that have comments from user U1, the returned response would contain the Post Object with list of 2 comments both made by user u1. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right. If you have concern about dublicate you can use Set<Post>